# Modifying Alert Subscription Template

Tags: alert, email, 2007

Is there a way I can customize the alert subscription email sent to users when they subscribe (or their subscription added by System Administrator) to a list for Alerts?

I've gone through `Microsoft.Sharepioint.ApplicationPages.SubNewPage` but the method that adds alerts is too cryptic :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change it for all users in your entire SharePoint Farm, you'd want to make a copy of the Alerts .xml file in the 12-Hive\Templates directory, then update the file as you would like it to display.

Comment: Hi Craig I was not able to find Alerts.xml file anywhere on my box. Though there is alerttemplates.xml which I've already customized and does not contains template for subscription notification email.

Answer (score 1):

It's `AlertTemplate.xml` @ *[12|14]\TEMPLATE\XML*

Cheers.